# Interesting behavior of __construct() and __destruct() in PHP

Tags: php

I was testing a class whilst developing my app and just like any other quick-lazy-method-tweak I did an `echo` in

```
function __construct(){
   parent::__construct();
   echo "yaba daba doo"; 
   exit();
}
```

Now, after few tests and all, I thought of checking if the class has been fully compiled thus I wrote:

```
function __destruct(){
   echo "ends here"; 
   exit();
}
```

Interestingly, even though there was an `exit` in `__construct` , it still executed `__destruct`!

As per my knowledge exit 'kills' the process, doesn't it?

`__destruct` is called upon when the object has no more reference for the class.

Does that mean, `exit(0)` does not kill the process on priority?

Is it a PHP bug? because, IMO the script shouldn't go any further?

Comment: [PHP 5 introduces a destructor concept similar to that of other object-oriented languages, such as C++. The destructor method will be called as soon as there are no other references to a particular object, or in any order during the shutdown sequence.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's all in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.destructor).

> The destructor will be called even if script execution is stopped using exit(). Calling exit() in a destructor will prevent the remaining shutdown routines from executing.